# How to use shm_open to open an existing Shared Memory object

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I do not want to create a new shared memory object, if it does not exit. Rather return an error in such a case. I want only open if it already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [shm_open(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).

If `shm_open`  is *not given* the `O_CREAT` flag it will fail if the name does not exist, like [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) does. If `O_CREAT` *and* `O_EXCL` are given, it will also fail if the name exists. It is said in [shm_open(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) that failure can happen with:

> ENOENT 
>     An attempt was made to shm_open() a name that did not exist,
>                 and O_CREAT was not specified.
>
> EEXIST Both O_CREAT and O_EXCL were specified to shm_open() and the
>                 shared memory object specified by name already exists.

On some Linux systems, you might use `/dev/shm/` to know about the current POSIX shared memory segments.

Comment: Second question: how to know if I have opened an existing shared memory existing, I am using O_CREATE | O_RDWR.

Comment: Third question, i am using shm_open to create/open a shared memory object and mmap for mapping it into process' virtual address space. f the process crashes and fails to clean up shared memory it stays until system shutdown.Though it this contradictory with what has been mentioned on wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory under Support on UNIX platforms.

Comment: No, the address space would go if the process is terminated.

Comment: I am talking about the file which gets created in /dev/shm, it remains if process gets crashed without cleaning up the shared memory (unmap and shm_unlink).

Comment: I want if there are no other references to shared memory by any process, and the crashed process was the only one referring, that shared memory object and file should get cleaned up?